# how to search for a string between 4 strings

Tags: c++, string

i want to write a program that gets about 4 strings from the user and then asks the user to type a string to see if the string exist in one of those 4 strings that have been entered.could you please correct my mistakes.thank you.(i use dev c++)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    int x,y,i;
    string z[40],a;
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        cout<<"type 4 strings";
        cin>>z[i];
     }
        cout<<"type a string to search ";
        cin>>a;
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {   if(strcmp(z[i],a)==0)
        cout<<z[i];
        else
        cout<<"error";
    }
    getch ();   
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Post the compiler errors in full and point out which lines of the code they are.

Comment: You dont need to use strcmp, when using string, you can just do z[i] == a. And please fix your indentation.

Comment: @Rapptz string z[40],a; ?

Comment: It isn't included anywhere.

Comment: my problem is with the if(strcmp(z[i],a)==0).i added <string> but it didn't have any effect.this (z[i] == a) was effective but the program prints the error part as well.

Comment: @user2589043, as it goes through the array it will print out error for each string that doesn't match, and the string if it does match. If you want to only print out one or the other set a bool found to false outside the search loop, and if found set found and break. After the search loop print either the string or error based on found.

Comment: You could also use std::find from algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't mix C style string functions (`strcmp`) with C++ `std::string` - it works fine to compare C++ `std::string` types with regular `if (str1 == str2) ...`, so there is no need to use `strcmp` here.